# Exclude certain files ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild

I want to include in an item group query files that match:
Web.*.config  but be able to exclude one of them.

I've tried this but doesn't seem to work:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="Web.*.config"/>
    <FilesToDelete Include="@(Files)" Condition="%(FileName) != 'Web.Base.config'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="Web.*.config"/>
    <FilesToDelete Include="@(Files)" Condition="%(Filename) != 'Web.Base'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Filename doesn't exclude the extension...